# Can I use an if statement to break a while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

Basically what I want is to have the program run and start back at the beginning until a command is typed. I have the repeat part working, but I can't get the loop to break when I want it to. I was trying to use an if statement to take the input and use it to break the loop. I've seen it done in tutorials, but I can't get it to work for me. I understand the break statement is to exit a loop, I'm wondering if it is possible to use the break statement in an if statement like so:

```
while True:
    i == input('Type a letter:') #They type a letter
    if i == quit: #If they type "quit" this executes
        print('Goodbye') #The program says goodbye
        break #Ends the loop
    else:
        print("Your letter is", i) #If they type anything else, it gets printed
```

With this for me it just prints,:

```
Type a letter: quit
Your letter is quit
Goodbye
Type a letter:
```

if I type it, not breaking the loop. If it's not possible, does anybody have another way that I could get the same result, having the loop end when I type something like "quit"? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if` doesn't break. `break` does. If that isn't working, then the `if` condition is faulty, and you should print out some values like `print(i == quit)` before the if statement to see what's really happening

Answer (score 6):

You need to set `i` with a single equals sign (this may have been a typo in your post).

```
i = input('Type a letter:')
```

You also need to put `quit` in quotes to make it a string. As you have it, you're comparing the user's input with [the builtin `quit` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit), so they'll never be equal.

```
if i == 'quit':
```